# How to download file from the server using Jquery and Spring Controller?

Tags: jquery, spring

I need to download excel file from the output path, but I am not able to do so.

Here is my Jquery Code

```
$("#download").click(function(){
    if($(this).data('clicked', true)){
        $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url :"downloadFile",
               contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function(result) {
                    alert('File Download');
               },
               error:function(exception){
                   alert('Error Occured during file Download');
                   console.log('exception',exception);
               }
            }); 
    }
});
```

Here is my Controller Code:

```
@PostMapping("downloadFile")
    @ResponseBody
    public void downloadResult(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{
        try {

            File file = new File(outputPath + fileName);

            if (file.exists()) {
                String mimeType = context.getMimeType(file.getPath());
                System.out.println();
                if (mimeType == null) {
                    mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                }

                response.setContentType(mimeType);
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

                OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int b = -1;

                while ((b = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, b);
                }

                fis.close();
                os.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Requested " + fileName + " file not found!!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
```

I need an pop which arises for Download or Save Option in Browser.

Help is appreciated,
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I am not able to open the file, check image below.

[image]

Changes done as per #StanislavL answer

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/downloadFile")
    public void downloadResult(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{
//CODE
}
```

JSP Page (Javascript)

```
$("#download").click(function(){
    if($(this).data('clicked', true)){  
    window.location="http://localhost:8080/IRI-AXCO/downloadFile";                      
    }
});
```

Comment: what are the errors are you getting ? Please pass url as "/downloadFile"

Comment: Actually Thats the excel file which I need to download, All the excel datas are coming in the browser console

Answer (score 0):

Mapping should start from `/`

Change the mapping to `@PostMapping("/downloadFile")`

Also no need to AJAX call. You can use normal GET mapping and just set `window.location = TheURL`

Comment: Hi, I have done as you said but I am not able to open file, Its showing currupted

Comment: Have you changed both mapping to @GetMapping and JavaScript to use window.location?

Comment: Try to set `response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");` and check file name. Check file size, call `os.flush()` before closing

Comment: File name is not coming fully !